# Need help saving my broken cactus

Tags: cactus

[image]

My cactus has recently broken but it is still connected on one side. I don't know what to do. Can he be saved or is he going to be lost?

Comment: Why did your cactus break? An accident (hit by some object) or "naturally" (so probably some diseases)?

Comment: I'm thinking naturally. I checked him today and he was broken like the image I placed. I've checked the inside and there is no sign of rot, it looks healthy besides the broken spot.

Answer (score 1):

I know this happened to your cactus years ago.  I just thought it be nice for it to have an answer.

- Make a clean cut off the bottom
- Let sit out 2-3 weeks or more letting the cut completely callous (turn mostly white)
- Plant it very gritty soil
- Bury up to half of the cactus in the soil
- DO NOT WATER
- Place in bright sunny location
- In 2-3 weeks check to see if it wiggles easily
- If so, water it. If not, put back for another week or two
- Let the soil completely dry out
- Water it
- Repeat for lifetime of the plant.